# IdentityServer4: How to add roles to current user in api?

Tags: c#, authorization, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got a IdentityServer for the identity part for e few application. Each application has a api and a webgui. So far so good. Now I want to secure the api over the Authorize[Role="Admin, …"] attribute.

Adding roles to the claims on the IdentityServer don't make much sense, because each application has different roles and each user can be assigned to different roles depending of the application. I tried to implement rules over policy which worked fine, but with this solution I can't do "or" rules for the authorization (User should be in role Admin or Management to be authorized for this action). So this isn't a option too. I think the solution should be, creating a service that adds the roles to the current user, but I have no clue how I should do that.

After several hours of search I still don't find something that fits this situation and I can apply on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer simply authenticates and returns a principal with claims. That's pretty much it. Everything else is handled by your backing store. If you've integrated with Identity, in other words, you'd add roles to users in the standard way you'd do that with Identity.

The next issue, though, is that claims (which roles are) are sent with the principal and importantly, not updated. The only way to get updated claims is to get a new principal, which generally involves re-authenticating. In a typical web application scenario, you'd invalidate the security token, which would prompt the user to login again. This should also have the effect, from an API perspective, of causing a 401 response when a protected endpoint is requested, which then should lead the client to retrieving a new access token from your auth endpoint.

As far as doing something like authorizing if the user is in admin or management roles, policy-based authorization is perfectly capable of handling that. I'm not sure why you think it cannot. You can literally create something like an `AdminOrManagementRequirement` along with an associated handler. Then you'd just applied the `Authorize` attribute like:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOrManagement")]
```

Of course, utilizing whatever name you registered the policy under in `Startup`.

Comment: Roles in my case are more a thing of authorization than of authentication. In this case, roles don't belong into the claims. See this article about this in section "What about roles?": https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/ . If I wouldn't host the IdentityServer by myself and consume it over OpenId for example from Google, I wouldn't have the roles in the claims too.

Comment: Policies don't work because I have more than two roles per application. For example, In one I've got 4 (Employee, Control, Management and Admin). Only with this 4 roles, I would have do to create a ton of policies for every combination. Now imagine, I have to add a 5th role in the future...

Comment: Well, first, that's entirely due to using roles wrong. Roles should correlate to a specific privilege, i.e. can edit, can view, etc. Admin is acceptable as a shothand for "all the roles". Viewed in that light, roles applied to a particular controller/action should not actually change. Second, Authorize can handle OR out of the box. When you pass a list of roles, you're saying any of those roles are good. Where you can get into issues is with applying multiple Authorize attributes, which then makes them ANDs, requiring all the roles.

Comment: If you do end up need complex AND/OR combos, thats where policies come in.

Comment: For example, you can create a policy like CanEdit, and then in your handler you define whatever goes along with that: roles, group memberships, company affiliations, whatever. If something changes, you need only change the handler.

Comment: For example, I've got a Controller Holidays. Then I should create policies like CanCreateHolidy, CanEditHoliday, CanDeleteHoliday, CanReadHoliday? Or should I make them more general?

Comment: That's just one idea. And they should be more general. You don't need a policy per discrete type unless there's different rules governing the specific access to that type. The point is that policies are extremely flexible and can handle pretty much any auth scenario. You just need to figure out what makes the best sense for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Best practice would be to assign roles to a user and then assign those roles to "Application Roles" within your IdentityServer.  Within your application you would check for the presence of the "Application Roles".

This allows you to decouple properties of a user with the business logic of your applications.

Comment: If I understand your solution correct, I should create for every connected application to the IdentityServer a separate resource? I keep this in my mind as a last possible solution. But how the write in your link, if a role is more a authorization thing than a authentication, which is the case here, it shouldn't belong to the IdentityServer. If I wouldn't host the IdentityServer by myself and consume it over OpenId for example from Google, I wouldn't have the roles in the claims too.

Comment: Yes, you would create a new set of roles for every application and also for every incoming trusted provider.  You would then need to create a set of rules which map incoming principal claims and roles to application roles.  Those application roles are what you'd check against within your application.  This layer of separation allows for you to consume various identity providers without needing to adjust for them within your application